# Context [/heatclinic] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am new to java spring. For developing an example web app I followed the link [http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started]. Initially it is working without errors. I wanted to switch my web app to mysql. So I follow the link [http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial]. Also I need to deploy the war file into my tomcat manager. After building my web app using mvn clean install, I am trying to deploy it in tomcat manager. For that I include the plugin for tomcat into my site's pom.xml. I got the following errors in my terminals when I start the deployed war file.

```
[ERROR] 09:59:37 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blMergedDataSources' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webDS' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [jdbc/web], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blMergedDataSources' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webDS' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [jdbc/web], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blMergedDataSources' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webDS' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [jdbc/web], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:384)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:445)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 64 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
... 71 more
Nov 24, 2014 9:59:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 24, 2014 9:59:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/heatclinic] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: a) did you mean "healthclinic" ? b) the error is self-explanatory: "Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager'" which mean (most chances are) that either `blPersistenceUnitManager` is not defined in the xml/annotations or that the xml is malformed and should be corrected.

Comment: thank u so much. I mean heatclinic, it is the project name.

Comment: which xml file contain the blPersistenceUnitManager bean defifnition?

Comment: I have no idea how the file is called - it's your code... I pointed to your bean xml

Comment: Dude, you'll have to debug you code... read the error and look for the field that fails loading (`persistenceUnitManager` which should be setup with `blPersistenceUnitManager`).

Comment: I fix the problem by changing the port number in my MySQL's conf file to 3306. After that added a the jar file `hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar` into my tomcat lib folder..